# Selenium, how to start Firefox with addons?

Tags: python, firefox, selenium

I want to load the Firefox Addon RequestPolicy. This is how i tried it:

```
rp = open(wd + "/requestpolicy.xpi")
firefoxProfile = FirefoxProfile()
firefoxProfile.add_extension(rp)

self.driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefoxProfile)

self.usr = user.User(self.driver, username, password, world)
self.usr.login()
```

No error, [according to the Docs](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/FirefoxDriver#Running_with_firebug) it should work, but it doesn't, it still starts without the addon.

Next thing i've tried is calling it this way:

```
self.driver = webdriver.Firefox(browser_profile=firefoxProfile)
```

Output:

```
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'browser_profile'
```

But this is an aspect of python i dont know much about. I got that idea because the [source](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/trunk/py/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py) looks that way.

Answer (score 7):

I don't have enough Stackoverflow *rep* to leave a comment on your question, and unfortunately I don't know the answer to your question, but for what it's worth you need to call `webdriver.Firefox()` with **firefox_profile**, not **browser_profile**, as you have done.

See also: http://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/trunk/py/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py#33

Answer (score 7):

It took me a few hours to find a solution.

All you need to do is download your extension as .xip file.

And then add this line to your code:

```
driver.install_addon('/Users/someuser/app/extension.xpi', temporary=True)
```

Replace *"/Users/someuser/app/extension.xpi"* with path to your extension .xip file.

Comment: this method does not exist in C# API - Profile.AddExtension does not work either ...

Comment: yes, because we are talking about Python :)

Answer (score 5):

what I did and worked was:

```
profile=webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.add_extension("/home/.../.mozilla/firefox/zrdb9ki8.default/extensions/{d10d0bf8-f5b5-c8b4-a8b2-2b9879e08c5d}.xpi") # for adblockplus

profile.set_preference("extensions.adblockplus.currentVersion", "2.8.2")
Fox = webdriver.Firefox(profile)
Fox.get(website_Url) #https://.....
```

Answer (score 1):

Additionally you should not open the xpi file directly. Instead try to just give the address:

```
firefoxProfile.add_extension(wd + "/requestpolicy.xpi")
```